# Resolve JUnit5 MultipleAssertions / assertAll( ) in JGiven-Testreport

Tags: java, junit5, jgiven

I'm using JGiven and JUnit5 for automated Software tests.
The Then-Stage I'm currently using, asserts a stream like so:
assertAll(executableList.stream());

which works great, but in the JGiven Testreport this looks like only one Assertion, which is not ideal.

Does anyone know if there is a way to have every single assertion listed in the JGiven HTML-Report?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.